# Ignite UI for Angular - how to use a cell template from code

Tags: angular, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular

I am just investigating [this grid](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/grid), and am trying to work out how to use a "cell template" from code.

Using their tree-grid-conditional-cell-style-2 sample, I have put the following:

```
    <ng-template #bodyTemplate igxCell let-val>
        <div style="background-color: rgb(50, 205, 63)">
            <span> from template {{val}} </span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>

   <igx-tree-grid igxPreventDocumentScroll 
                #grid1 [data]="data"
                primaryKey="ID" foreignKey="ParentID"
                height="350px">
                <igx-column *ngFor="let c of columns"
                        [field]="c.field"
                        [header]="c.header? c.header : c.field"
                        [cellStyles]="c.cellStyles"
                        [bodyTemplate]="c.bodyTemplate">
                </igx-column>
   </igx-tree-grid>
```

And in the TypeScript code I have

```
    @ViewChild('bodyTemplate', { read: TemplateRef })
    public bodyTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
   ...

    public ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.data = FOODS_DATA();
        this.columns = [
                    { field: 'ID', header: 'The ID'  },
                    { field: 'Name', bodyTemplate: this.bodyTemplate }, // <-- trying to use template
                    { field: 'UnitPrice' },
                    { field: 'AddedDate' },
                    { field: 'Extra' }
            ];
```

There are no errors, but the template is not being applied in the UI.

I am assuming it is `bodyTemplate` column property we use.

Why is this not working?

### Update

I could get this to work by using `cellTemplate` in the markup:

```
    <igx-column *ngFor="let c of columns"
        [field]="c.field"
        [header]="c.header? c.header : c.field"           
        [cellTemplate]="c.bodyTemplate"> <--------------
    </igx-column>
```

I did not find this as I was trying to type my columns, ie in the code behind I have `public columns: Partial<IgxColumnComponent>[];`

But cellTemplate does not seem to be a member of `IgxColumnComponent`?
So not sure why this is (as it works)?

Answer (score 1):

Both template and code behind definitions are correct. The [IgxCellTemplateDirective](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/blob/master/projects/igniteui-angular/src/lib/grids/) is @ContentChild of the [IgxColumnComponent](https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular/blob/master/projects/igniteui-angular/src/lib/grids/columns/column.component.ts#L788).